# Eclipse autocomplete similar to Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to get IntelliJ-like autocompletion in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685257/any-way-to-get-intellij-like-autocompletion-in-eclipse)

Is there a way to make Eclipse autocomplete work in a manner similar to one found in NetBeans? I lack completing to the next common part (i.e. type "me", I got suggestion Message, MessageArchive, MessageRouter so the 'tab' would complete to the "Message") and also auto suggesting on "." (or "enter") when there is subsequent possibility.

Tiny things but the lack of them is extremely frustrating…

Comment: OK, to clarify - after typing "ma" I use Ctrl+space to bring up suggestions, but from there onwards it works kinka weird (see my explanation regarding competing to the next common part and subsequent possibiliteis)

Comment: It turned out that the option that I was looking for was **"Insert common prefixes"** under _Java->Editor->ContentAssist_

Answer (score 6):

Goto `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assits`
In the column Auto activation triggers for Java column, enter this:

```
.qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm_QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM
```

Add any other keys you want. You're done.
You'll have the same effect as Netbeans

Comment: cool, works quite nice, a bit slow tho

Comment: @Wojtek: ya it is slow, but you can increase the auto activation delay under content assist so that you can type faster.

Answer (score 4):

Try typing "me" and then pressing Ctrl + Space.

Answer (score 2):

Well if the shortcut: *Ctrl+Space* doesn't fireup autocompletion, you will need to activate it in your Eclipse IDE.

To do that, go to: *Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->ContentAssist* and there you can set the parameters that you want.

[EDIT]: [Here is a capture](http://data.imagup.com/5/1112613791.png) to help you with.

Comment: that's not it - please see my comment to the question.

Comment: Ok! However, have you checked the preferences to see if there are some parameters that you can set so that the autocompletion tool can fit to your needs?

Comment: Yes, but none of those seems to bring me even remotly to what I have described :(

Answer (score 1):

The auto complete functionality should be turned on by default. Eclipse pop up a auto complete box after pressing the "." or you can manually do this by pressing STRG + SPACE on PC or CMD + SPACE on a MAC