# Any way to get IntelliJ-like autocompletion in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm stuck with Eclipse in one project and I would like to have autocompletion similar to that of IntelliJ - two major problems are:

- Start typing and Eclipse would automatically suggest all possibilities
- When there is item selected in dropdown list you can accept it not only with enter key but with dots, spacebars...

Comment: why not ask a question about how to coexist with IDEA and Eclipse on the same project (if that's the reason you're stuck with eclipse)?

Comment: is it possible to work on the same project on a disk in IDEA and then ECLIPSE ? will there be any corruption or risk of loss of data

Comment: This post solved your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991208/type-ahead-autocompletion-in-eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991208/type-ahead-autocompletion-in-eclipse here solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something like that in Eclipse I think, certainly in the Eclipse Helios. When typing you press CTRL+SPACE, or when you typed variable name '.' will start auto-complete options.
Also [here](http://www.netalive.org/swsu/archives/2005/04/instant_autocom.html) someone suggests to change auto complete delay settings to 0.

BTW you can also accept your selection with space bar, for sure.

**EDIT:** 
Why not consider using NetBeans, my personal favourite. There you have an option to show auto-completion on start typing any Java Identifier Part. This would then look exactly as you want it. (in NetBeans `Tools->Options->Editor->Code Completion`, there in Language box select Java and finally check Auto Popup on Typing Any Java Identifier Part).

Comment: If you've ever worked in both apps, then you'd realize you cannot compare Eclipse's autocomplete with IntelliJ's autocomplete ;)

Comment: @askmo Yea I have not much experience with IntelliJ. But from the problem description it seems that you have all this features in NetBeans, though in Eclipse I see no way of doing it.

Comment: I still think that IntelliJ has the best autocomplete (intellisense) tool. It does have other bad things, but with regard to autocomplete, I find it the best. Nevertheless I do agree that NetBeans is better than Eclipse, however Eclipse is prefered tool for Android development.

Comment: Yea I do agree with your argument. Maybe one day I will try IntelliJ once more. Best Regards

Answer (score 106):

Go to Window → Preferences → Java → Editor → Content Assist.
In the column "Auto activation triggers for Java", enter this:

```
.qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm_QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM
```

Add any other keys you want. You're done. That answers your first query.
As far as second one goes, I think it already exists.

Comment: I was planning to port to IntelliJ fbut after this tweek I don't think I need to do that. :)

Comment: Also make sure to remove code recommenders java proposals from Window → Preferences → Java -> Editor → Content Assist → Advanced. It speeds it up a lot. Switch it to just java proposals.

Comment: why is it not enabled by default?

Comment: Bye bye `CTRL-SPACE`

Comment: +1000, Eclipse can do so many things, it's a shame that a lot of them don't get used because they are hard to spot. There should really be a tooltip on the input fields, it doesn't help that the info of what an option does are retrievable from the help, there should just not be the need to search for them in the first place, the options I'm looking at are right there in that dialog and if I just need to hover on them to know what they do and decide about using them or not, I will do that, and if I have to start looking for that in help pages I won't, just like the vast majority of people.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Eclipse Code Recommenders [1] or Codetrails Connect [2]. They make Eclipse' code completion intelligent.

[1] http://eclipse.org/recommenders/

[2] http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codetrails-connect-community-edition/

Answer (score 2):

I have to say NO. I moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ because of the intellisense and inability to make Eclipse behave like IntelliJ (or if you come from the .NET environment: inability to make Eclipse intellisense behave like ReSharper in .NET).

Do you HAVE TO work in Eclipse? I do 98% of work in IntelliJ, then convert the project into Eclipse project (IntelliJ can still access it) and finish it in Eclipse. Maybe you could try this solution.

Comment: -1 This gives the wrong answer to the question, incorrectly assumes that resharper is the reason for the Visual Studio intellisense AND tries to push the OP into buying a product that the OP doesn't necessarily need.

Comment: @stepanian There is no buying. It's free to use. ;)

Comment: You need the Ultimate Edition to do anything useful like Servlets, SQL, etc.

Comment: I have been using it for Android development only and I don't need anything to buy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since Eclipse Juno, Code Recommenders Intelligent Java Proposals replaced the old JDT's Java Proposals.

It afford "Intelligent Code Completion" function, like IntelliJ did in a way.

You can get something useful through the link below:

http://code-recommenders.blogspot.jp/2012/07/code-recommenders-10-code-completion-on.html